# JQuery onDocument load Create Folder with an name from a field value

Tags: jquery, directory

I need to create a folder in a structure when the document has finished loading and name this folder with a value held in a hidden field with an id of xField.

Is this possible to achieve in Jquery?
If so can someone post some code to show me how?

**EDIT**

I have a web application which has a record type in it called solutions when a new solution is started a reference is generated, then using a WYSIWYG editor the user writes a solution document, there maybe a need for images for this document and as such these will need to sit in a folder with the solution reference as its name, I am trying to automate this process so the folder exists to allow the user to just upload images to that folder only.

Thanks

Justin

Comment: You do not have access to the client machine with Javascript and jQuery (since jQuery is javascript). And Javascript does not have access to the server except trought AJAX.

Comment: Do you need this code to run from a website? Could it be run in a local application like (HTA), in that case you could create a folder through the ActiveX.

Comment: this will need to create a folder on the server from which the application is being served

Comment: Then read @Jleagle answer. Ajax+PHP to create folder is way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible in jQuery (if you use some server side too!) - It doesnt sound like a very good approach though, maybe tell us what you are trying to do and we could suggest the best method?

To do what you are asking you would need to use AJAX (lots of code examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) to pass the folder name to PHP, which could then create the folder where you need it. The PHP end would only need to be a couple of lines if all you want to do is add a empty folder.